# How to handle databreach?

Tags: mongodb

what is the immediate action to be taken from a Mongodb dba when we come to know our data is compromised or open to public without our knowledge.  what are the actions to be taken immediately so that we dont damage more of our client data which is the must most important?

Comment: Voting to close as 'tip of the iceberg'. I think that phrase was *made* for a question like this. Good luck with your breach Manu.

Comment: Talk to your legal department.  Also, look around if there is anything you can do to strengthen your security.

Comment: Reading [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85456/what-security-considerations-should-i-take-when-planning-do-to-incident-response) and similar questions on [security.se] might be helpful.

Comment: Step 1: remove DB from public access.

Comment: Once this is done, you should codify such a policy so that you're not scrambling around for one in an emergency situation. You should have had this policy in place before your DB was connected to the internet.